# Advance Filtering Results on MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

I would like to show results with a sum of all items per customer with the code shown below but it only shows 1 item.

MySql Data

Acct_Table

```
cust_id         cust_name          cust_group
1001            Customer A         normal
1002            Customer B         vip
1003            Customer C         normal
```

Trans_Table

```
cust_id     trans_volume     trans_details     trans_date
1001        2                milk              2018-01-01
1002        1                coke              2018-01-01
1001        1                beer              2018-01-02
1003        5                bottled water     2018-01-03
1001        1                coffee            2018-01-03
1001        1                coke              2018-01-03
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Trans_Table.cust_id,
    Trans_Table.trans_details,
    SUM(Trans_Table.trans_volume) netvolume
FROM Trans_Table
INNER JOIN Acct_Table
    on Trans_Table.cust_id = Acct_Table.cust_id
WHERE
    Trans_Table.trans_date '2018-01-01' AND
    '2018-01-03' AND
    Acct_Table.cust_group IN ('normal','vip')
GROUP BY Trans_Table.trans_details
```

the result will have only 2 items on 1001 and i suspect that the 'coke' is added on 1002. How can i show the total volume of the items of each details by each customer.

Thanks.

Comment: You should show us the _exact_ output you expect here.

Comment: i wanted to get the result as: 1001 milk 2, beer 1, coffee 1,coke 1 ; 1002 coke 1; 1003 bottled water 1.  i want this data to be shown on a chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just aggregate by both the user and item:

```
SELECT
    a.cust_id,
    t.trans_details,
    SUM(t.trans_volume) AS total_volume
FROM Acct_Table a
INNER JOIN Trans_Table t
    ON a.cust_id = t.cust_id
GROUP BY
    a.cust_id,
    t.trans_details;
```

[image]

But this approach has the drawback that the result would only contain tallies for the user/item combinations which actually occur in your data.  If you wanted a report showing all users and all items, even with zero transaction volume, then we need to do some more work:

```
SELECT
    a.cust_id,
    t.trans_details,
    COALESCE(SUM(t.trans_volume), 0) AS total_volume
FROM Acct_Table a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT trans_details FROM Trans_Table) td
LEFT JOIN Trans_Table t
    ON a.cust_id = t.cust_id AND
       td.trans_details = t.trans_details
GROUP BY
    a.cust_id,
    td.trans_details
ORDER BY
    a.cust_id,
    td.trans_details;
```

[image]

This format of data is more ideal for plotting (I think), because it is regular and shows every customer and every possible item, along with the sum of volume for each pair.

Comment: thanks @Tim Biegeleisen, Data is showing the appropriate results now. I will add filter on dates and the group.